# Johnson 9.9 2 stroke wont idle anymore

Tags: two-stroke

I have a  1999 Johnson two-stroke 9 hp outboard motor. I have a 10 foot pelican that I put it on but the other day I almost flipped the boat after making a sharp turn, water got all in the boat about a foot high. I emptied out the water but my motor would no longer run. The gas tank was elevated to where it was out of the water but may have got some water in it. my motor wouldn't run until I eventually hit the throttle to get it started. But now if i idle it, it will die within 5-10 seconds. I put seafoam in the gas with no luck. I checked the fuel pump filter and its not dirty. (Just took that one flathead screw off that atacthes to it) dont know if thats all i gotta do. I checked for leaks from hoses while it runs and dont see anything. Whats going on

Comment: Did the air intake (at the front of the carb) go under water?  You might take the air filter out, in case it's soaked.  Also, maybe take the spark plug out, see if anything interesting comes out when you tip it that way.

Comment: The motor from my knowledge didnt go underwater at all. It just went sideways but had the cowling on. It possibly could have though so im mot going to rule it out. I will check the air intake and spark plugs today and see if anything comes out the spark plugs.

Comment: If you don't find anything with those, I'm about out of bullets.  (I haven't looked at an outboard in 50 years; they might possibly have changed since then.)  But, you might look at the exhaust/muffler - running 5-10 seconds reminds me of small 2-strokes with a plugged spark suppressor.